# Lightning Scheduler: Is there a way to remove the location search and instead, immediately display a list of territories?

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, lightning-scheduler

I am hoping to find a way to display a list of locations (Service Territories) to the Lightning Scheduler user instead of the default google location search.

`instead of this:`
[image: Default Service Territory Selection]

`immediately show the list of locations`
[image: List of locations]

Answer (score 4):

For anyone wondering, I figured out a way to partially solve this. Run the flow in debug mode and select the location that you want to show up and click next. Check the debug log for the "LocationScreen" section. In the debug log, you will see the variables LocationLatitude and LocationLongitude assigned their own number. Find the variables in your flow and set their defaults to those respective numbers.

What will now happen is that the location that meets those coordinates will immediately show. You can also set the LocationDistance variable's default to pull in nearby locations.

Hope this helps! I just started using Lightning Scheduler myself.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Pass in the {!ServiceAppointment.ServiceTerritoryId} from the URL to the Flow with the SFid of the Service Territory. Then you don't restrict to lat long and can pass in other territory ids as needed. Passing parms to LS inbound flow (guest) https://.force.com//s/?AssociateLocationID=0Hh1g0000000I6WCAU&AssociateID=1234567- where the AssociateLocationID if passing in the SFid of the Service Territory. You just need to add the variables to your flow (AssociateLocationID in this example) and embed the flow on a community/experience site in this case or without a community. PS - Guest User is a pain as is scheduler. Lots of room for improvement for LS so just keep that in mind :)